# Can I write logs to ETW using Serilog?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog, etw

Is there any way to write logs directly to ETW using Serilog? I can't see any sinks or information on theirs website. I'm quite surprised that there are not ETW sinks? Or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: What about writing your own sink?

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, but before that I wanted to be sure that's the only way to capture etw events.